# Google Cloud Function Error: Exception: Bad response from application: 500

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, google-cloud-functions

I was running a cloud function to trigger a DAG on composer. After deploy GCF and dropping a file to trigger the function, the #500 error is showing up in log, however when I call the function in "test function" it was successful - finished with status: 'ok'.

I am new to GCF, I couldn't understand what causing the error and need some help on the error log message for trouble shooting.

this is the Main.PY I use (Got it from Cloud doc, I put xxx replacing the actual value on client_ID & server_ID):

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.compute_engine.credentials
import google.auth.iam
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google.oauth2.service_account
import requests


IAM_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam'
OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'


def trigger_dag(data, context=None):
    """Makes a POST request to the Composer DAG Trigger API
    When called via Google Cloud Functions (GCF),
    data and context are Background function parameters.
    For more info, refer to
    https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#functions_background_parameters-python

    To call this function from a Python script, omit the ``context`` argument
    and pass in a non-null value for the ``data`` argument.
    """

    # Fill in with your Composer info here
    # Navigate to your webserver's login page and get this from the URL
    # Or use the script found at
    # https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/composer/rest/get_client_id.py
    client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-l1sqmeccbhj607i99su1uavn0l8jcgbk.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    # This should be part of your webserver's URL:
    # {tenant-project-id}.appspot.com
    webserver_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-tp'
    # The name of the DAG you wish to trigger
    dag_name = 'DAG_Dev_cf_trigger_test'
    webserver_url = (
        'https://'
        + webserver_id
        + '.appspot.com/api/experimental/dags/'
        + dag_name
        + '/dag_runs'
    )
    # Make a POST request to IAP which then Triggers the DAG
    make_iap_request(webserver_url, client_id, method='POST', json={"conf":data})

# This code is copied from
# https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iap/make_iap_request.py
# START COPIED IAP CODE
def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method='GET', **kwargs):
    """Makes a request to an application protected by Identity-Aware Proxy.

    Args:
      url: The Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL to fetch.
      client_id: The client ID used by Identity-Aware Proxy.
      method: The request method to use
              ('GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')
      **kwargs: Any of the parameters defined for the request function:
                https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py
                If no timeout is provided, it is set to 90 by default.

    Returns:
      The page body, or raises an exception if the page couldn't be retrieved.
    """
    # Set the default timeout, if missing
    if 'timeout' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['timeout'] = 540

    # Figure out what environment we're running in and get some preliminary
    # information about the service account.
    bootstrap_credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
        scopes=[IAM_SCOPE])

    # For service account's using the Compute Engine metadata service,
    # service_account_email isn't available until refresh is called.
    bootstrap_credentials.refresh(Request())

    signer_email = bootstrap_credentials.service_account_email
    if isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                  google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials):
        # Since the Compute Engine metadata service doesn't expose the service
        # account key, we use the IAM signBlob API to sign instead.
        # In order for this to work:
        # 1. Your VM needs the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam scope.
        #    You can specify this specific scope when creating a VM
        #    through the API or gcloud. When using Cloud Console,
        #    you'll need to specify the "full access to all Cloud APIs"
        #    scope. A VM's scopes can only be specified at creation time.
        # 2. The VM's default service account needs the "Service Account Actor"
        #    role. This can be found under the "Project" category in Cloud
        #    Console, or roles/iam.serviceAccountActor in gcloud.
        signer = google.auth.iam.Signer(
            Request(), bootstrap_credentials, signer_email)
    else:
        # A Signer object can sign a JWT using the service account's key.
        signer = bootstrap_credentials.signer

    # Construct OAuth 2.0 service account credentials using the signer
    # and email acquired from the bootstrap credentials.
    service_account_credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials(
        signer, signer_email, token_uri=OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, additional_claims={
            'target_audience': client_id
        })
    # service_account_credentials gives us a JWT signed by the service
    # account. Next, we use that to obtain an OpenID Connect token,
    # which is a JWT signed by Google.
    google_open_id_connect_token = get_google_open_id_connect_token(
        service_account_credentials)

    # Fetch the Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL, including an
    # Authorization header containing "Bearer " followed by a
    # Google-issued OpenID Connect token for the service account.
    resp = requests.request(
        method, url,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
            google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
    if resp.status_code == 403:
        raise Exception('Service account {} does not have permission to '
                        'access the IAP-protected application.'.format(
                            signer_email))
    elif resp.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            'Bad response from application: {!r} / {!r} / {!r}'.format(
                resp.status_code, resp.headers, resp.text))
    else:
        return resp.text


def get_google_open_id_connect_token(service_account_credentials):
    """Get an OpenID Connect token issued by Google for the service account.

    This function:

      1. Generates a JWT signed with the service account's private key
         containing a special "target_audience" claim.

      2. Sends it to the OAUTH_TOKEN_URI endpoint. Because the JWT in #1
         has a target_audience claim, that endpoint will respond with
         an OpenID Connect token for the service account -- in other words,
         a JWT signed by *Google*. The aud claim in this JWT will be
         set to the value from the target_audience claim in #1.

    For more information, see
    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount .
    The HTTP/REST example on that page describes the JWT structure and
    demonstrates how to call the token endpoint. (The example on that page
    shows how to get an OAuth2 access token; this code is using a
    modified version of it to get an OpenID Connect token.)
    """

    service_account_jwt = (
        service_account_credentials._make_authorization_grant_assertion())
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    body = {
        'assertion': service_account_jwt,
        'grant_type': google.oauth2._client._JWT_GRANT_TYPE,
    }
    token_response = google.oauth2._client._token_endpoint_request(
        request, OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, body)
    return token_response['id_token']
# END COPIED IAP CODE
```

Requirements.txt

```
requests
requests_toolbelt==0.9.1
google-auth==1.14.1
google-api-python-client==1.7.4
oauth2client==3.0.0
google-cloud-storage
```

Also like to enclose the error log message: (showing "TypeError: expected string or buffer" at the end)

```
Exception: Bad response from application: 500 / {'Date': 'Mon, 25 May 2020 02:18:10 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '3356', 'Server': 'gunicorn/19.9.0', 'Via': '1.1 google', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"'} / '\n<html>\n <head>\n <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">\n </head>\n <body>\n <div class="container">\n <h1> Ooops. </h1>\n <div>\n <pre>\n\n ____/ ( ( ) ) \\___\n /( ( ( ) _ )) ) )\\\n (( ( )( ) ) ( ) )\n ((/ ( _( ) ( _) ) ( () ) )\n ( ( ( (_) (( ( ) .((_ ) . )_\n ( ( ) ( ( ) ) ) . ) ( )\n ( ( ( ( ) ( _ ( _) ). ) . ) ) ( )\n ( ( ( ) ( ) ( )) ) _)( ) ) )\n ( ( ( \\ ) ( (_ ( ) ( ) ) ) ) )) ( )\n ( ( ( ( (_ ( ) ( _ ) ) ( ) ) )\n ( ( ( ( ( ) (_ ) ) ) _) ) _( ( )\n (( ( )( ( _ ) _) _(_ ( (_ )\n (_((__(_(__(( ( ( | ) ) ) )_))__))_)___)\n ((__) \\\\||lll|l||/// \\_))\n ( /(/ ( ) ) )\\ )\n ( ( ( ( | | ) ) )\\ )\n ( /(| / ( )) ) ) )) )\n ( ( ((((_(|)_))))) )\n ( ||\\(|(|)|/|| )\n ( |(||(||)|||| )\n ( //|/l|||)|\\\\ \\ )\n (/ / // /|//||||\\\\ \\ \\ \\ _)\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nNode: 6003c629d1dc\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1982, in wsgi_app\n response = self.full_dispatch_request()\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1614, in full_dispatch_request\n rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1517, in handle_user_exception\n reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1612, in full_dispatch_request\n rv = self.dispatch_request()\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1598, in dispatch_request\n return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/api/auth/backend/default.py&#34;, line 32, in decorated\n return function(*args, **kwargs)\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py&#34;, line 78, in trigger_dag\n dr = trigger.trigger_dag(dag_id, run_id, conf, execution_date)\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py&#34;, line 98, in trigger_dag\n replace_microseconds=replace_microseconds,\n File &#34;/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py&#34;, line 62, in _trigger_dag\n run_conf = json.loads(conf)\n File &#34;/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py&#34;, line 339, in loads\n return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n File &#34;/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py&#34;, line 364, in decode\n obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\nTypeError: expected string or buffer\n</pre>\n </div>\n </div>\n </body>\n</html>'
at make_iap_request (/user_code/main.py:125)
at trigger_dag (/user_code/main.py:45)
at call_user_function (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py:214)
at invoke_user_function (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py:217)
at run_background_function (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py:383)
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi, you probably need to edit your question to be more specific if you want a good answer here. As a minimum, you're expected to provide some code that causes the problem you describe. Check out the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: thanks for the hint, updated the question/format and providing more details on codes for main.py

Comment: It seems like you are calling a GAE service that is having an exception because there's a `json.loads()` at method `_trigger_dag` in file `trigger_dag.py` line 62 that is receiving an object that is not either a string or a buffer.

Comment: Hi Ajordat, thank you for your help, I updated the code as json=data, the function is properly working as I expected now.